# Setting constant value buildConfigField in Gradle when assembling production version

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have defined the following `buildConfigField` under `productFlavors` in my gradle file:

```
buildConfigField "java.util.Date", "buildTime", "new java.util.Date(" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "L)"
```

My question is will this field change each time they open up an app or only when it's first build/ installed on their device? If yes, how do I make it a constant?

Sorry for such a stupid question, I'm new at working with gradle. Any help appreciated

Comment: it will only change when you build app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You execute the `System.currentTimeMillis()` call in Gradle when your project is built and then set `buildTime` to something like `new java.util.Date(1483522309324L)`, so the value is already a constant in your project that is calculated fixely at build time as its name suggests.